# ‌Building a Java project cloned from git using Ant fails

Tags: java, git, maven, ant, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to build [JICOFO](https://github.com/jitsi/jicofo) on an Ubuntu server 16.04.1. After installing default JDK & JRE and setting JAVA_HOME variable cloned JICOFO and tried to built it by following commands:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/jitsi/jicofo.git
$ cd jicofo
$ ant dist.lin64
```

When try to build project via `ant dist.lin64` command first I got the following error:

```
/home/xaq/jicofo/build.xml:54: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant:dependencies
Cause: The name is undefined.
```

After resolving Maven problem by copying `maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar` to `lib` folder [bunch of dependency errors](http://www.writeurl.com/text/gbet7034g5oin80bc5hs/puozwfuk56wn8bl1eqxn) occurs when trying to build the project.

My question is: How to automatically resolve all dependencies for building such a project? isn't it what `Ant` and `Maven` are proposed to do?!

Comment: Ant has never been intended to solve dependencies. Maven is intended to do this by its repositories but this projects looks like misunderstanding the concept of maven repositories and building up a reliable structure to build that project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch all project dependencies I just ran the following command from where `pom.xml` file resides (here in jicofo folder):

```
$ mvn install
```

This command despite the name won't install `Maven`, instead it will fetch all project dependencies from appropriate repositories.

You need to have `Maven` installed before running this command. That's an easy job:

```
$ sudo apt-get install maven
```

Now `$ ant dist.lin64` will build project successfully.